# What is the best way in SQL Server to take backup before the data get purged?

Tags: sql-server, backup

My case is in SQL Server, I want to take backup of a database. The transnational data in the database is purged based on a retention period, say 90 days. The requirement is to have an archive on another server for up to 10 years, so that user can run ad-hoc queries directly on the stored data. I guess neither creating a replica nor standard backup using SSIS is not beneficial. The question is what sort of solution is the best fit with the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - You can setup replication from transactional "current" database to Archive database. While setting up replication, you can configure the delete activity to NOT replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Have an empty db on live server. Call it "tempo"
Every 90 days, move data from live db to tempo db
Backup tempo db and restore it on archive server
Copy data from tempo to archive database
Drop tempo db